# Very slow queries in MS Access with joined MS SQL table via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, oledb

What is the best solution when I would like to use an Access front-end application with some linked table (via ODBC) from MSSQL Server?

The difficulty of this for me is that I have to use complex queries with many multiple joins (and functions called from queries). 
It is very-very slow because of the joins between the two DB (and there is a lot of data in some tables, the 2 GB Access mdb limit is the reason of the MSSQL DB upgrade).

Pass-through query doesn't help because of the joined Access tables. 
With OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'... it is still slow in SQL Server too. I tried ODBC linked view with WHERE clause from MSSQL, but it 
seems as slow as the full table.

I have to move all of joined Access tables to the MSSQL DB and convert all queries to Pass-Through? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Cross system joins are going to be horribly slow no matter how you slice it. Linked tables are really terrible for performance. I would move your Access tables to SQL Server and get all of your data in a single database.

Comment: In a lot of cases, in place of a PT query, I recommend that you create a view server side, and then link that view. This setup tends to be the least amount of work, and the resulting linked table can be filtered with the " where " clause of the open form, or open report. As such, you find they work better  then a PT query for reports, and even forms.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to move all of joined Access tables to the MSSQL DB

Yes, definitely.

> and convert all queries to Pass-Through?

Not necessarily, only those that are still slow.

"Normal" INNER JOIN queries, using only linked tables from one server database, are handled by Access and the ODBC driver in a way that everything is processed on the server. They should be (more or less) as fast as when run on the server (or as Pass-Through query).

Only "complex" queries, especially involving multiple INNER and OUTER JOINs, won't work like that. You'll notice that they are still very slow when running on linked tables. These need to be changed to Pass-Through queries.

---

Edit: I just noticed

> functions called from queries

You can't call VBA functions from PT queries, and they will again kill performance when called from Access queries running on linked MSSQL tables (because they have to be processed locally).

You'll need to learn to create **views** in MSSQL, probably also user defined functions and/or stored procedures.
In the long run, you'll find that views are actually easier to manage than PT queries.

Answer (score -1):

I, too, encountered this problem, but the solution is quite straightforward. Just access the ODBC connection through Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC 32bit/64bit. Then, proceed to halt the tracing by selecting "Stop Tracing Now" under the Tracing tab. This will successfully resolve the issue.